# How to pretty print json string from the output of Redis Client on command prompt on Windows 7?

Tags: redis, command-prompt, redisclient

I am running redis client (redis-cli) on Windows 7 command prompt. I am storing data in my redis cache through my Spring Boot Java application in JSON serialized form. When I print data using `GET <key>`, the output is not pretty printed, as in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way I can pretty print JSON in the command line?

Comment: Try `redis-cli get userById::195 | jq .`